# Undefined ARM processor library issue in C

Tags: c, eclipse, undefined-reference, infineon

Building a C program for an Infineon microcontroller using DAVE 4.4.2 (an IDE based on Eclipse) I get this error:

```
'Building target: mcu.elf' 
main.c:(.text.ERU0_3_IRQHandler+0x696): undefined reference to `arm_mat_init_f32'
'Invoking: ARM-GCC C Linker'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is a simplified overview of my code.

```
#include <arm_math.h>
[other included libraries]

void my_function() {
  arm_matrix_instance_f32 M;
  float32_t zeros33[3][3] = {0};

  arm_mat_init_f32( &M, 3, 3, &zeros33);
}
[other defined functions]

int main(void) {
  my_function()
  [other stuff]
}
```

While in the header `arm_math.h` I see the definition of the function which is said to be undefined.

```
void arm_mat_init_f32(
arm_matrix_instance_f32 * S,
uint16_t nRows,
uint16_t nColumns,
float32_t * pData);
```

What I suspected is that the issue might have lied in the incorrect data type being used, or the incorrect use of pointers in passing the arguments. I tried to  remove the `&` in front of the matrix variables, but unsuccessfully. On the same line of thinking, I also tried to use different data types for the definition of the matrix data: `float32_t` and `float`.

Looking at various warnings and info messages, I noticed one next to the `arm_mat_init_f32` declaration saying `Expected 'float32_t *' but argument is of type 'float32_t (*)[3][3]'`. I therefore also tried to pass the address of a "normal" variable `float32_t zero = 0.0f`, and just `0.0f`. They both still resulted in the build to fail due to the undefined function.

A last observation is that if i right-click the function call in my code, and ask to "go to Declaration", the right function is found, in the right file.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `undefined reference` is a linker error, so I guess you are not correctly linking your executable to the `arm_math` library?

Comment: @MikevanDyke Thanks. I forgot to mention that `arm_math.h` is in the same folder as `main.c`, along with many other header files which are included with no issue. I can't imagine linking problems with this configuration.

Comment: @MikevanDyke I think you put me on the right track. I now realise the header is in the folder, but not the `.c` file. I'll do some research and update the question in a bit.

Comment: Have you tried [these](https://www.infineonforums.com/threads/823-DAVE-TIP-of-the-day-Things-need-to-do-when-use-math-functions) steps? Did you get the DSP lib frmo the [CMSIS repo](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS) or how did you download it?

Comment: @MikevanDyke Thanks for that link. I wasn't able to find something like that. Apart from downloading the latest library, I followed those steps unsuccessfully. I need to be careful with updating the library because I did not initiate this project and am only expanding it. I'm afraid a full update of the libraries might break the existing code (I'm especially scared about things that would compile fine but in particular cases misbehaving in run time in a way C finds acceptable). Once again, you probably put me on the right track. I'll investigate further in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using DAVE, a solution to the problem is adding an APP via Project/Add new APP. Then select System/CMSIS_DSP, and press "Add". The program needs to be fully rebuilt.

In this way, DAVE configures all necessary environmental variables and links so that the `arm_math` library is included.